# Python Regex Problems with Whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do a python regular expression that looks for lines formatted as such ([edit:] without new lines; the original is all on one line):

```
<MediaLine Label="main-video" xmlns="ms-rtcp-metrics">
  <OtherTags...></OtherTags>
</MediaLine>
```

I wish to create a capture group of the body of this XML element (so the `OtherTags...`) for later processing.
Now the problem lies in the first line, where `Label="main-video"`, and I would like to not capture `Label="main-audio"`

My initial solution is as such:

```
m = re.search(r'<MediaLine(.*?)</MediaLine>', line)
```

This works, in that it filters out all other non-`MediaLine` elements, but doesn't account for video vs audio. So to build on it, I try simply adding

```
m = re.search(r'<MediaLine Label(.*?)</MediaLine>', line)
```

but this won't create a single match, let alone being specific enough to filter audio/video. My problem seems to come down to the space between `line` and `Label`. The two variations I can think of trying both fail:

```
m = re.search(r'<MediaLine L(.*?)</MediaLine>', line)
m = re.search(r'<MediaLine\sL(.*?)</MediaLine>', line)
```

However, the following works, without being able to distinguish audio/video:

```
m = re.search(r'<MediaLine\s(.*?)</MediaLine>', line)
```

Why is the 'L' the point of failure? Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any help.

And to add to this preemptively, my goal is an expression like this:

```
m = re.search("<MediaLine Label=\"main-video\"(?:.*?)>(?P<payload>.*?)</MediaLine>", line)
result = m.group('payload')
```

Comment: Consider using XML parser instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, these lines are all mixed in with thousands of other non-XML lines. I guess after the first match I could then try to parse the XML. I'll look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, `.` doesn’t match a newline, so your initial solution didn't work either.  To make `.` match a newline, you need to use the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag (aka `re.S`):

```
>>> m = re.search("<MediaLine Label=\"main-video\"(?:.*?)>(?P<payload>.*)</MediaLine>", line, re.DOTALL)
>>> m.group('payload')
'\n  <OtherTags...></OtherTags>\n'
```

Notice there’s also an extra `?` in the first group, so that it’s not greedy.

As another comment observes, the best thing to parse XML is an XML parser.  But if your particular XML is sufficiently strict in the tags and attributes that it has, then a regular expression can get the job done.  It will just be messier.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In the actual file, this is all on one line, and there are no new-lines. The first solution did work. I'll update the question. Ignoring the new line problem, any tips? Thanks again.

Comment: @JustinMcBride Make all the quantifiers lazy in the regex in your question.